# Create SubPage with OneNote API

Tags: onenote-api

Is it possible to create a Subpage using the `OneNote API's` in O365?

More specifically, can the API create a subpage in an existing page?

I'm able to create `pages` and `sections`. Unfortunately, I can't find documentation on subpages.
Documentation to create pages = https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/onenote-create-page

[image: Make Subpage]

Example: Manually creating a sub-page.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2016/02/04/change-page-level/
There is an example patch request at the link.

Comment: Yes.  The documentation you provided will change the page level by indent/make the page as a sub page.  

I'm looking for the ability to add Subpages to an existing page.  I don't see this functionality.  In addition, I couldn't find the ability to change the position of a page in a section.

Comment: Sorry both these functionality (add a subpage and change the page order) are not supported currently. I will add these to our backlog list and let you know when it gets done. Thanks!